# What's the word for drugging someone?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I remember having learned it from the TV. But I can't remember what it is now.
It's a verb synonym of drug or poison. It means someone slips some drug into someone's food or water. The drug may be just some sedatives.

Comment: For a single-word alternative verb to ***drug** [someone]*, look at [various synonyms](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=synonym+drug+sedate+medicate+tranquilise&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-GBGB569GB569&oq=synonym+drug+sedate+medicate+tranquilise&aqs=chrome..69i57.20382826j0j0&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8) such as *sedate, medicate, tranquilise*, etc. Words like *spike, lace* are things you do to *something the person consumes*, rather than directly to the actual person.

Comment: You were asking for the *noun* [_roofie_](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/176888/19279), not a verb.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think in relation to alcohol, you may be thinking of "Slip a Mickey" or "Mick" or "Roofie".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mickey_Finn_%28drugs%29
http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=slipped%20a%20mickey
https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091116141136AAOITR5

Comment: I thought "roofie" was specifically rohypnol.

Comment: YES!Roofie is the word that I am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @Rupe: technically maybe, but not everyone's a qualified pharmacist, and I'm pretty sure that drugs with related effects get called by the wrong names from time to time ;-)

Comment: I meant in common usage rather than technically. Could be another localised difference though. I think in the UK people might stretch the usage to other drugs when the purpose is to disinhibit the target but no further.

Comment: @Eli Fair enough if this is the word you'd forgotten. Just so long as you know that some people (here at least) will presume a "date rape" context if you were to use it.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jlIMmuMQozc

Comment: @SteveJessop - yeah, I only found out this month that the infamous _roofies_ that I'd always heard from american film/television sources isimplyly [flunitrazepam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flunitrazepam). Here - in Australia - it's commonly-understood to refer to a hypnotic in the context of _date rape_.

Comment: @Rupe yes. And i'll bet mick(ey) also stands for a specific substance.

Comment: @nl-x That may be true of the etymology of "Mickey Finn", but to my knowledge it's not how people understand it now. Do you think otherwise? I'm not picking arguments here, just trying to help the OP not to use a phrase in a way that's liable to be misunderstood.

Answer (score 23):

***[lace](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lace)***

> to add a small amount of a powerful substance (such as alcohol, a drug, or a poison) to (something, such as a drink)

Comment: The "drug or poison" in the question makes me think "spike" is better here, especially if it's being done without the recipient's knowledge (which seems likely though it isn't explicit in the question).

Comment: @Rupe: It seems like there are more than one correct answer.

Comment: "Lacing" could describe the action of putting the stuff into the drink/food, but it isn't a "synonym of drug or poison". You can lace something with something that's desirable, and it can be used in describing the normal make-up of the thing (eg "a trifle laced with sherry").

Comment: @Rupe: Yes but it still covers the sense. Spike is the action of adding also and it can be used for a desirable thing also. Check the meaning [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spike?show=0&t=1402331038). You can lace a drink with a drug or a poison. You can spike a drink with a drug or a poison. Spike and lace is almost a synonym. Maybe spike is used more than lace for adding a drug and a poison, though I don't think so.

Comment: Also 'an adulterated drink' but more formal and less common.

Comment: @ermanen Sorry but I disagree. "Spiking" a drink is something you do without the drinker's knowledge or consent. "Lacing" *just* means adding a small amount of something, with no connotations like that.

Comment: Spike is a modern Americanism, Lace has a far richer history in the English language

Comment: @Rupe: I disagree with you also. Both can be used interchangeably. You can check the dictionaries and usages.

Comment: @ermanen Maybe it's a geographical thing. Here in the UK they're definitely not interchangeable. One could serve someone a "coffee laced with brandy" and it could be exactly what they'd ordered. "Spiked" would mean that it wasn't, which fits the question better. If you use "laced" you'd need something else to get across the fact that the extra (and negative) ingredient had been *slipped* into the drink. "Spiked" does all that on its own.

Comment: @Rupe In the US at least, *spiked* is definitely used "as ordered", but I've personally heard it used far more often referring to *alcohol*, as in ["eggnog spiked with rum"](https://www.google.com/search?espv=2&q=%22spiked+with+rum%22+-lipstick&oq=%22spiked+with+rum%22+-lipstick&gs_l=serp.3...5719.7817.0.8137.10.10.0.0.0.0.208.925.6j2j1.9.0.starcmoon...0...1.1.45.serp..8.2.348.mmnQb6XmFqo). For other drugs, *laced* seems more prevalent.

Comment: People in Australia lace their drugs with more drugs

Answer (score 22):

That would possibly be "spiking" (i.e., spiking someone's drink). Hope this helps!

Comment: spiking means to add alcohol, if i'm not mistaking

Comment: Spiking can mean adding alcohol to a non-alcoholic drink or adding something, eg roofies, to a (perhaps alcoholic) drink.

Answer (score 1):

If the drug being slipped is a psychedelic like LSD, the word *dose* is often used.

Example from [SF Weekly](http://www.sfweekly.com/2012-03-14/news/cia-lsd-wayne-ritchie-george-h-white-mk-ultra/)

> It's been over 50 years, but Wayne Ritchie says he can still remember
>   how it felt to be dosed with acid.
>
> He was drinking bourbon and soda with other federal officers at a
>   holiday party in 1957 at the U.S. Post Office Building on Seventh and
>   Mission streets. They were cracking jokes and swapping stories when,
>   suddenly, the room began to spin. The red and green lights on the
>   Christmas tree in the corner spiraled wildly. Ritchie's body
>   temperature rose. His gaze fixed on the dizzying colors around him.

Example from [Time Magazine](http://healthland.time.com/2012/03/23/the-legacy-of-the-cias-secret-lsd-experiments-on-america/):

> The article mentioned a narcotics officer he once knew and noted the
>   officer’s involvement in the LSD experiments; then it hit Ritchie that
>   he might have been secretly dosed on the day he went crazy.

Example from [The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/film/2011/aug/06/lsd-ken-kesey-pranksters-film):

> On board were half a dozen travellers who called themselves the Merry
>   Pranksters and a jar of orange juice laced with LSD.

...

> After Cassady drove the bus off the road in Arizona, Kesey dosed the
>   party with LSD.

For the skeptics, headlines using the word "dosed" to describe people being given drugs without knowing it:

*High school teacher recounts being dosed* ([BoingBoing](http://boingboing.net/2009/02/05/high-school-teacher.html))

*Security guard ‘dosed’ with GHB and LSD at B.C. music festival* ([Canada.com](http://o.canada.com/news/national/b-c-music-festival-investigating-after-security-guard-dosed-with-ghb-and-lsd))

*Worst Science Article of the Week: The CIA Dosed a French Town With LSD!* ([Discover Magazine](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/discoblog/2010/03/15/worst-science-article-of-the-week-the-cia-dosed-a-french-town-with-lsd/#.U5sqSGRdXrM))

*R.I.P. "Oscar": Dog Dosed With LSD By Owners Dies After Being Struck By Car* ([The Smoking Gun](http://www.thesmokinggun.com/buster/animal-cruelty/lsd-dog-dies-765091))

*The Plymouth Diaries: That Time A Neo-Nazi Dosed Me With LSD* ([Remy Carreiro](http://remycarreiro.com/the-plymouth-diaries-that-time-a-neo-nazi-dosed-me-with-lsd/))

*Family Gets Dosed With LSD From Walmart Steaks* ([Bubblews](http://www.bubblews.com/news/2589140-family-gets-dosed-with-lsd-from-walmart-steaks))

*The History of "What if We Dosed the Water?"* ([Brainsturbator](http://www.brainsturbator.com/posts/86/the-history-of-what-if-we-dosed-the-water))

*Johnny Knoxville Was Dosed With Ecstasy While Filming 'Jackass Presents: Bad Grandpa' Promos* ([Huffington Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/10/10/johnny-knoxville-ecstasy-jackass_n_4077919.html))

And here's a "confession bear" meme somebody made:
[image: Confession Bear]

Comment: I've never seen/heard that before, and I read a *lot*. Interesting.

Comment: Those quotes are both compatible with the more normal use of "to dose" which is just to give someone a drug. Do the contexts make it clear that the drug is being slipped into (or even just added to) food or drink?

Comment: @Rupe Edited to add an additional quote from Time and the original article from SF Weekly that it drew from, as well as additional context from the Guardian.

Comment: @Robert I'm not convinced those quotes support you. The Time one explicitly doesn't, since it includes the word "secretly", and in the Guardian it seems natural to presume that they laced the drink themselves or at least that they knew about it.

Comment: @Rupe Added numerous headlines from less reputable sources. Linked articles make it clear that they are using "dosed" to mean without the victim's knowledge or consent.

Comment: @Robert Sorry, I haven't looked at them all. But the first couple certainly aren't convincing. Just because someone didn't know they were dosed, doesn't mean that the word "dosed" means they didn't know.

Comment: To be honest, if you tell me that that's how *you* would use it that's fine. I just don't think the links are particularly supportive.

Comment: @Rupe I'm not sure what you would consider convincing. If that's as specific as you can be about your misgivings then I can't see how to help.

Comment: All your examples are consistent with how I use the word, which is that "dose" means something more general than "spike". To me "spiking someone's drink" means "dosing it without them knowing". So I would often be able to use "dose" in place of "spike", losing some meaning but still being true. But not the other way around. Like I said, I'm happy to believe that "dose" means the *same* as "spike" for you and many other people. But your examples seem to be consistent with my understanding too, so I don't see them as supporting yours (or mine, for that matter). Hope it's clearer now